# Zabbix calculates data from empty items

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix keeps calculating values on unresponsive hosts from empty items.
[Screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUnXs.png)
I've tried to use formulas that should calculate data within the time shift but it doesn't work for me.
For example:

```
100 - last("vm.memory.size[pavailable]",#1,5m)
100 - last("vm.memory.size[pavailable]",300)
```

Is there any way to make Zabbix stop calculating data for empty items?
[Calculated item example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HzXv.png)

Comment: Probably the same author also tried reporting as a bug at https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBX-12025 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `last()` function, so Zabbix does just that - grabs the last value from the item.

You can try using `avg()` over some time period - in that case, missing values would make the calculated item fail.

Comment: It's a nice workaround and it works but I'm getting a bit different values when I'm using avg("item",300) comparing to last("item"). For example, item with last() gives me 217.65 MB of used memory while avg(300) (300 is default run interval for all my items) gives 217.18 MB, so I'm not sure, if it's going to work okay. When I'm using avg("item,"#1) with last 1 value it keeps working just like last("item") and don't stop counting values.

Comment: Could it be that `avg(300)` is picking up two values sometimes? If `#1` works for you, that's good, just note that in your last `avg()` example the quoting seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My working example:

```
Original Item:
Key: check.variable


Calculated item:
Key: check.variable.change

Check nodata >>>
Formula: nodata("check.variable","30")

If nodata true, set 0  >>>
Formula: change("check.variable") * (1 - nodata("check.variable","30"))
```